# Can we create drugs for AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

If we can somehow create an AI that shows and understands emotions, and some sort of virtual consciousness then will we also be able to write code that acts as drugs for the AI that provides feelings of euphoria and altered states of consciousness?

Comment: You can write code that interacts with other code in arbitrary ways.  That seems to be what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If we could theoretically create such an AI, then yes, I believe we could potentially create code to act as "drugs" (though not sure why we would want to aside from performance upgrades).

Comment: Well if the AI shows emotions then for the same reason we take drugs, to make it happy I guess, just a random thought I had.